# How to add one or more columns to a Data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a column with string "All". I tried `flattened=flattened.assign(col=["All"])` and also `flattened["Col"]="All"` but it does not work and i keep getting the 'str' object has no attribute 'assign' error.

Is there any way out. i have to add these dummy columns to ease copying of dataframe to a range of cells in excel

```
Flattened        Desired Output
Month A  B       Month A  B  Col
jan   ab bc      Jan   ab bc all
Feb   hi de      feb   hi de all    
Mar   al if      Mar   al if all 
Apr   ds fg      Apr   ds fg all
```

Comment: You really need to provide a sample set of data and your expected output

Comment: It looks like `flattened` is equal to a `str` and not a Pandas `DataFrame`

Comment: sample table and Desired ouput added

Answer (score 0):

you will have to assign a list of your column values: For ex:
`flattened["Col"]= ['All', 'All', 'All', 'All']`

Comment: the above is fine if there is only 5-10 rows  and i have more than 10000 rows, i will have to repeat 10000 times?

Comment: ok, then you could use dataframe's assign method like this:
`df.assign( col = 'All')`

Comment: tried. I get an error `'str' object has no attribute 'assign'`

Comment: Oh, I noticed the code you provided is this:
`flattened=flattened.assign(col=["All"])`
Please remove [], and simply provide 'All' as a string like this:
`flattened=flattened.assign(col='All')`
Now it should work fine!

Comment: You are working on a dataframe right? why does it say it has no attribute 'assign'? Please check the documentation: [link] (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

Comment: `flattened = pd.DataFrame(table.to_records())` this is how i converted a Pivot table to dataframe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215394/discussion-between-prin-and-biplab1985).

Comment: it worked fine. it always worked, my bad. i did not run the program from start. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it worked! If you like, please upvote the answer.